# Infragistics WebDataGrid in Sharepoint webpart

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infragistics, webdatagrid

I put the WebDataGrid (Infragistics) in a webpart using Visual Studio 2010 and deployed it to a Sharepoint portal.

The grid displays the data, however I am unable to use the Excel-like filters usually present in the headers.

Is there a specific property that needs setting?

Using version: Infragistics35.WebUI.Shared.v11.2, Version=11.2.20112.1019

Any help appreciated.

thanks,

KS

Answer (score 0):

To use the built in filtering you need to enable the filtering behavior.  For enabling behaviors, use the Behaviors dialog which can be opened by clicking the ellipsis on the Behaviors property of the WebDataGrid.

There are more details on enabling filtering in the [Filtering](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WebDataGrid_Filtering.html) topic in the NetAdvantage for ASP.NET help.